# Why java may throw OutOfMemoryError when it has a lot memory left?

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory

For example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory(); // 1216348160, ~1.2Gb
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory(); // 188997632, ~188Mb
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory(); // 93796384, ~93Mb
```

I thought that in such situation JVM will attempt to allocate more memory up to `maxMemory` limit, instead of throwing OOM.

In pre-java-7 days, this could happen if PermGen was exhausted, but now PermGen is replaced with unbounded metaspace.

There is a lot of free swap space on physical machine, so JVM should be totally able to allocate more memory.

Comment: Just a guess - are you (unintentionally) trying to allocate a huge array? That could easily cause this error even though you think there's enough memory (you'll get the exception before the memory is actually allocated, because there's not enough for the array).

Comment: @eran - I don't think so. Also, in that case JVM usually says 'OOM: Requested array size exceeds VM limit', and this doesn't happen here.

Comment: Take a look at this: [ideone.com/m0xTs0](http://ideone.com/m0xTs0). The error message just says "Java heap space". Might be implementation dependent, though.

Comment: Please show us the code for the memory allocation request which fails.

Comment: @MikeNakis - it happens somewhere in AWT-Windows thread, and doesn't show proper stack: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError\n  at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)\n  at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)\n  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Comment: @MikeNakis - I seriously doubt that gui thread will attempt to allocate 1Gb+ memory in one sitting, thus this question.

Comment: I think that the question should be "why is AWT failing with an OutOfMemoryError".  You do not really know how much it is trying to allocate.  It could be that due to a bug it is trying to allocate -1 bytes, which, translated to 32-bit unsigned, is 4GB.

Comment: It appears that others have encountered this before: http://sourceforge.net/p/docfetcher/bugs/159/

Comment: Even on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348511/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-even-if-there-is-enough-ram-available

Comment: Also, I vaguely seem to remember something like some crappy java gui giving up with an "OutOfMemoryError" when it was unable to allocate a windows object, (like, say, a Timer,) not really because it ran out of memory, but because too many windows objects of that kind were being allocated. So, check if you are creating too many (tens of thousands) instances of something.

Comment: @MikeNakis - yes, that seems like a valid proposition. I'll dig in some more.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a string array of size 1000000000 using the "new" operator. So this array is capable of holding 1000000000 object references. The memory as we know get allocated from the java heap. The max size of the heap (as per maxMemory) is 1.2 GB.

My theory (based on following math) - Assuming it is a 32 bit machine each object reference will take 4 bytes. So 1000000000 object references will take 4000000000 bytes which is close to 3.7 GB while max heap is only 1.2 GB. So this results in OOM java heap error.

-Madhu.